# Calculated result for inductance seems wrong?

Tags: rf, inductor, radio, frequency-modulation

I'm building an FM radio transmitter kit which includes an LC tank, where C is a tuner capacitor of ~30pF and the resonant frequency is ~100Mhz. The value of the PCB trace inductor, however, is not specified and I want to know what it is.

If I plug:
\$100000000=\dfrac{1}{2π\sqrt{L3\times10^{-11})}}\$

[into an equation solver](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/100000000%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%5Csqrt%7Bx3%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-11%7D%7D%7D/?origin=button) the result is apparently 52771500 Henries. That seems... a little off? Considering most of the FM transmitter examples I've looked at on the net are like, 0.5uH?

How do I work this out?

Comment: You seem to be doing a mathematical error. I'm getting \$ 84.43 nH \$ when I do the plugging in, which seems to be a reasonable number.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong then: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7uZH0jM.png)

Comment: Is the tuner capacitor the **only** capacitor in the LC tank or is there a fixed one in parallel? Please show the circuit diagramm.

Comment: @AshlynBlack: note how your link at the end claims that there is no solution. after their "switch sides" step they do crappy things to resolve that formula

Comment: Re: schematic (please don't sue me, Silicon Chip magazine) http://i.imgur.com/uyST5lQ.jpg

Comment: That equation solver is definitely outputting wrong results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a mathematical error as I specified in a comment. To clarify further, rearrange for L as follows.

$$
L = \frac{(1e8*2\pi)^{-2}}{3e-11} = \frac{1}{12\pi^2} \cdot \frac{1e-16}{1e-11} = 8.443e-8 H = 84.43 nH
$$

The equation holds and seems to yield a reasonable value.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the resonant frequency is calculated according to the following equation:

$$fr=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

Solving fo L you have

$$L=\frac{1}{4\pi^2Cfr^2}$$

Seting your values into it I found L= 84nH